# Non destructive methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a class which inherits from Array (in practice, it's just a mask for a multidimensional array).
I want to override its `to_a` method:

```
def to_a
    self.each.with_index { |el, i| el.map {|j| j} }
end
```

but this messes things up: when I try to test my function:

```
it 'should be non destructive' do
    a_board = Representation.new(@a_size)
    a_clean_board = Representation.new(@a_size)
    expect(a_board).to eq(a_clean_board)

    # Try to modify a_board
    arr = a_board.to_a
    arr.pop
    a_board.to_a.pop

    # Check that it stayed equal to a_clean_board
    expect(a_board).to eq(a_clean_board)
end
```

both calls to `pop` have side effects on the original board.

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably because it returns reference to the same object. To avoid this use `map` instead of `each` or use .dup at the end.

**UPD**

As I said, just use map. Like it's in functional programming where intentionally are no side-effects. Example:

```
class WrappedArr < Array
  def to_a
    map { |el| el.map {|el2| el2 } }
  end
end

w_arr = WrappedArr.new([[1,2], [2,3]])
# => [[1, 2], [2, 3]]

2.0.0p247 :012 > w_arr.to_a.object_id # always different as it is different object
#=> 70318090081080
2.0.0p247 :013 > w_arr.to_a.object_id
# => 70318095088040
2.0.0p247 :014 > w_arr.to_a.object_id
# => 70318095081540

# final test
2.0.0p247 :015 > w_arr.to_a.pop
# => [2, 3]
2.0.0p247 :016 > w_arr
# => [[1, 2], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: I was avoiding `dup` at the end since it doesn't return a deep copy of the object, and so inner arrays are passed by reference anyway. PS I read about `dup` being a not-so-good practice in Ruby, is that true?